# How to push github clone to new github repo?

Tags: git, github

I made a local clone of my own github repo, made a different project of it, and now I want to push it to github as a new repo. I am forced to create a blank repo on github first, and push into it, as it seems impossible to create a new repo by pushing into it. Now when I do so, I get a common error message:

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to matc
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

Cloning the remote (empty) repo into a dummy branch (suggestion elsewhere) didn't work here, and I cannot modify the settings of the remote repo either. I don't want to force anything, I want the history to be clear that at one time it was this other github repo.

I also tried to fork the original github repo, and merge with that, but forking my own repo on github doesn't do anything.

What is the best/cleanest way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need first register a repo(the blank repo you have created on github)in your local repo.

```
$ git remote add another_repo git@github.com:XXX.git
```

then you can push to this repo

```
$ git push -u another_repo master
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
```

It will create remote branch `master` and set it as default pushing branch.

Comment: I just tried that, same error message. Thanks for the suggestion.